# Solutions of $z^n = \overline{z}$ in dependency of $n$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. What are all solutions, for $z\in\mathbb{C}$, of $ z^n=\overline{z} $?

To solve it, I tryed to write the term in Polar-Form and than take the logarithm. Because of the "ln(r)" term I was unable to find a solution.

I also tryed to write $ z^n $ as a Binomial, but this was not helpful at all.

This question was asked as an early exercise in Advanced Mathematics 2.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Thank you, Gibbs.

Comment: Solutions definitely exist for n=-1 in which case any z of unit modulus solves it

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Assuming $z=re^{it}\neq 0$ (which may or may not be a solution depending on the sign of $n$), your equation is equivalent to$$r^ne^{int}=re^{-it}$$
$$r^{n-1}e^{i(n+1)t} = 1\tag{uses $r\neq 0$}$$
$$\implies r=1,(n+1)t=2k\pi$$
This is enough for you to enumerate the solutions. You must consider the cases $n=-1$ and $n\neq -1$ separately.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I think this is enough.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you're asking to solve:
$$r^ne^{ni\theta}=re^{-i\theta}$$
That is: $$r^{n-1}e^{(n+1)i\theta}=1+0i$$
$$\rightarrow r^{n-1}(\cos[(n+1)\theta]+i\sin[(n+1)\theta])=1$$
Thus $$r^{n-1}(1)=1$$, since when $\sin (x)=0, \cos(x)=\pm1$, and it can't be $-1$ here.

$\sin[(n+1)\theta]=0$ when $\cos[(n+1)\theta]=1$ $\rightarrow$ $(n+1)\theta=2k\pi$
and $r$ can only be $1$

If any part of this doesn't make full sense, please say so and I'll clear up the confusion.